# How to deal with large sums of floating points (C++)

Tags: c++, floating-point, precision

I'm trying to understand why computing determinant of a 3x3 matrix in this way gives broken results:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    const int dim = 3;
    std::vector<std::vector<float>> data;
    data.resize(dim, std::vector<float>(dim, 0));
    std::array<float, dim*dim> myArray = {
        -1000.0, -1000.0, -1000.0, 
        -1000.0, -1000.0, -1000.0, 
        -1000.0, -1000.0, -999.0
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < dim; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < dim; j++){
            data[i][j] = myArray[dim*i + j];
        }
    }
    float det = 
    data[0][0] * data[1][1] * data[2][2] + 
    data[0][1] * data[1][2] * data[2][0] + 
    data[0][2] * data[2][1] * data[1][0] - 
    data[2][0] * data[1][1] * data[0][2] - 
    data[0][0] * data[1][2] * data[2][1] - 
    data[1][0] * data[0][1] * data[2][2];

    float anotherDet = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        anotherDet = anotherDet + 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        anotherDet = anotherDet - 1000 * 1000 * 1000;
    }
    anotherDet = anotherDet - 1000 * 1000 * 999;
    anotherDet = anotherDet + 1000 * 1000 * 999;

    std::cout << det << " " << anotherDet << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is `-64 0`, whereas the real determinant of such matrix should be zero. My suspicion is that the error is related to the floating points precision, but I still don't get the logic for why such discrepancies happen.

I tried debugging, and indeed I found that there is a rounding error that gets carried on. `-2999000060` is the value of `det` in the middle of that large sum.

But if I try the following:

```
float det2 = 
    1000 * 1000 * 1000 + 
    1000 * 1000 * 1000 + 
    1000 * 1000 * 999 - 
    1000 * 1000 * 1000 - 
    1000 * 1000 * 1000 - 
    1000 * 1000 * 999;
```

It gives the correct value of 0, but only because its an arithmetic operation, and thus there are not rounding errors.

Edit: I understand now how operations with floats that big could carry some rounding error.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried using a debugger, but because ```float det``` is a one-liner, I can't really see whats going on in that sum.

Comment: @EOF If I try to explicitly write the determinant expression with numeric values, the result is 0 instead of -64. I still don't get why

Comment: Then split that big sum in multiple individual steps, using some temporaries; and check the value at every step.

Comment: @hao123 I have no idea what you mean. Maybe you should add your observations to the question, including a [mre]?

Comment: Unrelated: Here's [a way to define a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/4581301) that is significantly faster than the `vector` of `vector`s approach for small matrices. You'll recognize the trick it uses because it's exactly how `myArray` works.

Comment: @EOF Ok I'll edit my question

Comment: Do you get the same result for `det`  and `anotherDet` ?

Comment: Right! Understood now! Because it is a sum of integers, instead of floats

Comment: @hao123 Your example of `float det2 = 
    1000 * 1000 ...` is evaluated **as an integer type**. You won't see rounding errors there. To see this, change the first literal *to `float`*: `float det2 = 
    1000.f * 1000 ...`

Comment: What is your question here? What do you not understand about floating point error?

Comment: Replace all `float` with `double`.